# MongoDB and Mongolab.com

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb, mlab

Recently I discovered the power of noSQL database [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). After a lot of trial and error I was able to install it on my pc along with wampserver. Its running smoothly. Now the question I would like to ask is, that if I want to integrate the MongoDB service provided by [Mongolab](https://mongolab.com) on my shared hosting plan, is there any class available that helps me connect to the database? Like a php class version of the driver for php and mongodb. As it is not possible to install the driver on my hosting, because of no root access. So is there a raw class available as an alternative to the driver dll?

Comment: You might want to double-check with your hosting service. It's common for their PHP offerings to include the MongoDB PHP driver out of the box.

Comment: can you please list out some shared web hosting companies that provide mongodb? @jared

Comment: I believe that Rackspace offers a PHP product that has the MongoDB driver already installed. Or you could go with a PaaS provider like PHP Fog. They've got a great product and a plugin that makes integrating with MongoLab easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't install the driver, then the REST interface provided by MongoLab is your best bet - any language that can send/receive a HTTP request can use REST:

http://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-rest-api-for-mongodb